# ISAPI Extensions on IIS 7.5/Windows 7 (professional)

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I need to register a custom isapi extension on my web server, but I can't seem to find the option on my IIS 7.5/Win7 (pro) box.

On IIS 6 it used to be under "Home Directory" -> Configuration -> Wildcard application maps.

How can I achieve the same on IIS 7.5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Wildcard script mapping and IIS 7 integrated pipeline**
http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/

Answer (score 1):

See article [Developing IIS 7.0 Modules and Handlers with the .NET Framework](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/366/developing-iis-70-modules-and-handlers-with-the-net-framework/) and go at "Deploying the Assembly to the Server"